# Database Diff Tool

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

As a Java Developper using JPA/Hibernate, I am looking for a will help diff a database that has been generated by Hibernate with a production database.

I've already looked at LiquiBase's abilities [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/) which is quite nice... Unfortunlately it is plagued by some weird bugs:

- Re-Create Foreign Keys for no reason
- Re-Create Indexes for no reason

I'm not entirely sure that it's Liquibase's fault as much as the JDBC Driver Implementation that are not consistent with the specification. I would be probably be plagued by the same issues if I even tried to roll out my own.

I am looking for a non Java-based solution that would support:

- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- Oracle
- DB2

Answer (score 1):

I like [DB Data Difftective](http://www.datanamic.com/datadiff/index.html).

Comment: FYI - don't be put off by the single user licensing, look at the bundled packs they provide.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at ModelRight?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to diff or "patch" data values (not structure), then Open Source DiffKit will handle this nicely for you:

http://www.diffkit.org